# Allow user to resize html image in jeditorpane

Tags: java, html, image, properties, jeditorpane

I'm creating an application that, amongst other things, allows users to insert images on to a document. The document will be a jEditorPane and I am going to use HTML to insert the image because that way I am able to add print functionality. I don't see why I should need to change component because I was under the understanding that jEditorPane is the most powerful component of that type...

But anyway, inserting an image is alright, but I need to allow the user to change alignment and size atleast, and at the minute, I'm not sure how I can do that and that's what I'm asking you for.

I'd of thought that there would be some type of HTML code that, like, online WYSIWYG editors use - but I couldn't find anything! So does anyone know how to tackle my little problem, prefabably with what I've already got?

Thanks in Advance

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add some javascript to the project.
Check out http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/ for a WYSIWYG Editor in javascript, that you can linkt to a css file.

Comment: Okay, that's unfortunate seeing as jEditorPane doesn't support javascript and I don't want to use a java web browser project or something to allow javascript in the text component (if there is some standard code, I'd use that, but I don't know of it)! That is the type of thing I'm looking for though and if anybody knows of a way to do it that will work for me, please tell. But I do think I have a bit of a work around if it can't be done like I've said!